# c# LINQ where with nullable boolean fields

Tags: linq

I have the following query:

```
    where !(tf.Shipped.HasValue == true || tf.Ordered.HasValue == true || tf.Processed.HasValue == true)
```

Note that Shipped, Ordered and Processed are all nullable Boolean fields.

What I am trying to do is to check that if Shipped or Ordered or Processed have a value of true, they should NOT be in the result.

In my case Ordered is true but I am still getting this records. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Are you checking if `tf.Shipped` is true or if it has a value?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're checking whether the nullable bools *have a value*.
If that value is `false`, `HasValue` will still be true.

You probably want to write

```
where !(tf.Shipped == true || tf.Ordered == true || tf.Processed == true)
```

Comparing nullable bools is the only case where one should write `== true`.

However, you probably should not be using nullable bools in the first place.
Unless you have a meaningful distinction between `null` and `false`, you should use regular bools instead and save yourself a lot of headache.

Comment: Nullable bool are sometimes returned from libraries out of your control. In those cases, it's nice to know the proper way to deal with them. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: And sometimes nulls have a valid business meaning and required by the client, as much as they're a headache in database queries.